# Como desactivar para los test el middleware verify de laravel

Tags: laravel, test

estoy haciendo unas pruebas de permisos. Pero el middlware verify me esta molestando para estas pruebas ya que me arroja errores 500 por no estar verificado, lo que quiero hacer es desactivar el middlware en ciertas pruebas y centrar las pruebas en su objetivo principal (ya habra otras para las verificaciones).

Por jemeplo, con este test :

```
//GETs methods

public function testStaffCanNotAccessToSecurityIndex()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $user->assignRole('staff');

    Auth::login($user);

    $response = $this->get(route('admin.security.index'));
    $response->assertRedirect(route('forbidden'));
}
```

Si tengo el middleware verify :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','verify']], function () {
```

Me esta molestando, entonces lo que he probado es añadir un trait a los test (`WithoutMiddleware`) que se supone que ignora estos midds... Pero me da error 500. He acabado haciendo test yo manualmente y no da error.

Lo que pretendo es que este o no activado el midd verify en las rutas no afecte a estas pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado una manera, en cada clase de los test hay que crear esta funcion

```
protected function setUp():void
{
    parent::setUp();

}
```

y dentro de ella, desactivar los midds que uno quiera en cada caso, yo como solo queria desactivar el midd `verify` pues lo he dejado de la siguiente manera:

```
protected function setUp():void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->withoutMiddleware('verify');

}
```